# bool true value to bit 1 from Entity to Sql through public Nullable<bool>

Tags: c#, sql, ajax, wcf, entity

Got a weird problem I cant find a solution on.
I got a row in my Guest table
Which looks like this:

```
[GuestOnline] [bit] NULL,
```

So when I create a Guest I'm passing the value "true" from the client with a ajax call in json format to the WCF application that send the value to a property that looks like this for the moment.

```
[DataMember]
public Nullable<bool> GuestOnline
{
    get
    {
       return this.GuestOnline = true;
    }
    set
    {
        this.GuestOnline = true;
    }
}
```

The C# method that inserts the Guest to DB looks like this:

```
public Guest CreateGuest(Guest guest)
{
    context.Guests.Add(new Guest() { 
        GuestName = guest.GuestName, GuestOnline = true });
    context.SaveChanges();

    var result = context.Guests.First<Guest>(g => g.GuestName == guest.GuestName);

    return result;

}
```

This should clearly send the value "true" to my row in SQL. And the value should be converted to bit value = 1. But it doesn´t. I still get the value of NULL in my DB.
The Ajax call looks like this:

```
function createguest() {
    if (userName.value !== "") {

        var guestData = '{"GuestName":"' + userName + '", "GuestOnline":"' + "true" + '"}';

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:35709/ChatService.svc/guests',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: guestData,
            dataType: 'json'

        });
    }

};
```

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Not that this will solve your problem, but I recommend using FirstOrDefault instead of just First because it can also return null, whereas First with no results throws an exception.

Comment: You had right, it didn´t solve my problem. But I must thank you for optimizing my code.

Comment: I'm assuming your using Linq to Entities / Linq to SQL?  Because if Guest is already a mapped object you don't need to create a new object, but instead just commit the passed object into the database.

Comment: Yea that´s true, but the reason i started creating new objects in this autogenerated code is that the behaviour is not acceptable. But I just tried to let it be, and still the same result. Thank you again though,

Comment: I'm going to write an answer, but not 100% sure it's going to fix the issue you're having since the JavaScript may not be passing the correct data.  Certainly don't use quotes with the true value, or maybe pass a 0 or 1 instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using LINQ to SQL / LINQ to Entities and the Guest object has already been mapped to your database try this.  Lets also assume that `Guests` is the name of the entity created by the mappings that represents the table or structure containing `Guest` objects.

```
public Guest CreateGuest(Guest guest)
{
     guest.GuestOnline = true;
     context.Guests.InsertOnSubmit(guest);
     context.SubmitChanges(); //context.SaveChanges() for LINQ to Entity

     return guest;
}
```

This will use the `Guest` object passed to it directly and change the GuestOnline property to true.  It will then insert a record of the object's properties into the Table (or other entity structure) named `Guests`  Since there may be triggers to modify the record or other properties added when inserted (such as an auto-incrementing primary key value) the returned `Guest` object will contain all of the additional properties/column values.  The only time you need to actually search the entity/table for a specific object is if you are updating it.

Comment: I think you may need to remap your database.

Comment: I'll try that in school tomorrow again. Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `"true"` but `true` (without " ")

Comment: in ajax you mean? Thanks, but still same result though.